# Star Trek Armada: No sound in Windows 7

Tags: technical-issues, star-trek-armada-2

I successfully installed and ran Star Trek Armada on my Windows 7 machine, but the game doesn't have any sound.

Running it in compatibility mode as admin (Windows XP SP2), I don't have any problem visually. My only issue is that I don't have any sound.

Does anyone know how to fix that issue?

Comment: Armada or Armada 2? - Also, is there any sound options to the game?